# JavaScript Does not keep original encoding of URL parameter in Arabic

Tags: javascript, jsp, encoding, arabic

I use a JavaScript function to retrieve the parameters in the following URL
[http://localhost:8080/EastLaw/home4.jsp?tab=menu1&search=+الفقرة+الرابعة+من+المادة+الثانية+عشرة+من+عقد+التاسيس+المعدل+لالشركة+والمثبت+بالسجل+التجاري](http://localhost:8080/EastLaw/home4.jsp?tab=menu1&search=+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%A9+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9+%D8%B9%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%85%D9%86+%D8%B9%D9%82%D8%AF+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B3+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%84+%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A9+%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AB%D8%A8%D8%AA+%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%AC%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A)

Here is my JS function:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice
    (window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}
```

However, for search parameter I get the following string:
"+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D8....%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A"

I can't figure out how to set JavaScript to keep the original encoding.

Comment: "Keep original encoding"? URIs are always encoded. You could use `decodeURI` to decode a URI.

Comment: It worked thank you so much sir.